# Unable to parse JSON and extract value

Tags: json, go

I am new to Go lang and trying to parse a JSON of following form and get all objects in records array.

```
[
    {
        "records": [
         {"name":"value"},{"name":"value"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "records": [
         {"name":"value"},{"name":"value"}
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried using "github.com/tidwall/gjson" library but couldn't parse it. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: There is the [`encoding/json`](http://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json) package in the standard library, which should work well for almost all common use cases, did you try that? There are many tutorials around, this one looks fairly decent at a glance: https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/10/18/parsing-json-in-golang/

Comment: I checked that link too but unfortunately I wasn't able to figure out how to do it as I want all objects of records no matter which object record array belongs too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `encoding/json` package. First define variable type considering data structure of your json. Then use `json.Unmarshal()` to convert your json string to your variable.

**Example** : for your given structure I used `[]map[string][]map[string]string`

**Code:**

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    myJsonString := `[
    {
        "records": [
         {"name":"value"},{"name":"value"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "records": [
         {"name":"value"},{"name":"value"}
        ]
    }
]`
    myStoredVariable := []map[string][]map[string]string{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(myJsonString), &myStoredVariable)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", myStoredVariable[0]["records"][0]["name"])

}
```